# Android DarkActionBar theme not found parent with maven

Tags: android, android-maven-plugin

Im try to do a maven android proyect.

I have this in style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>
```

and this error

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 
 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

I have this in pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- Plugins -->
        <android-maven-plugin.version>3.8.2</android-maven-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>2.3.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <api.platform>16</api.platform>
        <eclipse-lifecycle-plugin.version>1.0.0</eclipse-lifecycle-plugin.version>
        <!-- Compilation dependencies, build.gradle -->
        <android-sdk.version>18</android-sdk.version>
        <android-buildtools.version>18.1.1</android-buildtools.version>
        <android-support.version>r7</android-support.version>
        <!-- Dependencies -->
        <androidannotations.version>3.0.1</androidannotations.version>
        <android.version>4.4.2_r2</android.version>
        <support-v4.version>r7</support-v4.version>
        <spring-android-rest-template.version>1.0.1.RELEASE</spring-android-rest-template.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>${android.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>compatibility-v13</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>compatibility-v7</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.1</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.1</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>compatibility-v7</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.androidannotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>androidannotations</artifactId>
            <version>${androidannotations.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.androidannotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>androidannotations</artifactId>
            <version>${androidannotations.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
            <version>${support-v4.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-android-rest-template</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-android-rest-template.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.charmas.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-reactive-location</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
            <type>aar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
            <artifactId>play-services</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.32</version>
            <type>aar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${android-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <nativeLibrariesDirectory>ignored</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>${android-sdk.version}</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>false</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>${eclipse-lifecycle-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>

                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>

                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-replacer-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.4.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>replace</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>

                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

And this error in pom.xml

```
dependency=[android.support:compatibility-v7:apklib:19.0.1:compile] not found in 
 workspace
```

In my maven dependecencies there are
compat-v4,v13, support-v4 compat-v7-appcompat, compat-v7 ...
Whats wrong?

Comment: Did you find any solution?